# how to show only li that have a certain class using javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, switch-statement, each

i have a few li's:

```
<ul>
    <li class="one"></li>
    <li class="one"></li>
    <li class="two"></li>
</ul>
```

and i am trying to show only the ones that have class="one"

I've tried something like:

```
var li = $('li');

    li.each(function(index, data)
    {
        var liClass = li.attr('class');

        switch(liClass)
        {
        case 'one':
              console.log(data);
          break;
        default:
            console.log('no match');
          break;
        }
    });
```

in this case `console.log(data);` should return:

```
<li class="one"></li>
<li class="one"></li>
```

but it returns them all

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var li = $('li');

li.each(function(index, data) {
    if($(this).hasClass('one')) {
          console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all elements that have a given class with jQuery using a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$(".one")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var li = $('li');
    li.each(function(index, data)
    {
var liClass = li.attr('class'); 
// You're selecting li which is the $('li'), and not element inside each(), use $(this) instead.
...
```

You're selecting li which is the `$('li')`, and not element inside `each()`, use `$(this)` instead

Use `var liClass = $(this).attr('class');`

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtdaK/)

Comment: nice, i can still keep my switch statement

Comment: As @x4f4r answered, even I prefer using `hasClass()`, I wrote the answer just to explain where you were making a mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

This should be really easy with jQuery, if I understand the question right?

```
console.log($('li.one'))
```